# Recurse to infinity and beyond, not ready

Tags: c#, recursion, .net

So I've been building a reusable class that will handle *recursion* and *copy directory one, to another directory.*  The folder structure is:

- Root (`D:\Arrigotti`)
- Source (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot`)
- Destination (`D:\Arrigotti\Backup`)
- Archive (`D:\Arrigotti\Archive`)

Those are the critical areas, for the example code I'm going to leave out some validation / error handling for simplicity sake.

```
public static class FileSystem
{
     public static void CopyDirectory(string source, string destination)
     {
           DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(source);
           DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();
           foreach(DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
           {
                 Console.WriteLine(@"Found Directory: {0}", dir.FullName);
                 if(Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(destination, dir.Name)))
                 {
                       Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to write directory...");
                       Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(destination, dir.Name));
                       Console.WriteLine(@"Created Directory: {0}", dir.Name);
                 }

                 CopyDirectory(dir.FullName, Path.Combine(destination, dir.Name));
                 FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                 foreach(FileInfo file in files)
                 {
                       Console.WriteLine(@"Found: {0}", file.FullName);
                       Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to copy...");
                       file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, file.Name), true);
                 }
           }
     }
}
```

Which I believe that part is quite accurate and working.  However, my problem stems in my call.

```
public static class Backup
{
     public static void Save()
     {
           string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
           foreach(string drive in drives)
           {
                DriveInfo diagnose = new DriveInfo(drive);
                if(diagnose.VolumeLabel == @"Backup" && diagnose.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                {
                    CopyDirectory(
                          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Source"],
                          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Destination"]);
                }
            }
      }
}
```

The code is running it looks like smooth sailing at this point, it completes five out of the hundred directories of web-sites it is copying then it randomly throws an exception (I left error handling out, for simplicity but this is the error.)

> IOException: The device is not ready.

It randomly stops *reading* and *writing*

I'm not entirely sure why this would occur, any advice would be terrific.

Comment: I had this with my own backup application.  I put a semaphore on the copy operation itself and all was fine after that.

Comment: What I found with CopyDirectory is that if any file in the directory causes an exception, it skips the remaining files and that leaves the target drive in an indeterminate state.

Comment: @GayotFow I think that is what is happening, you should post that as an answer.  That would be really good to know for future visitors.  It truly was an odd error.

Comment: The answer has already been accepted and voted upon.  But you REALLY and REALLY do not want to use CopyDirectory if you want to have confidence in your backup app.  My experience is that you need to inspect and handle every file so that you can be sure that every single file is accounted for: either by success or failure on the target.  Otherwise, to put it bluntly, your app is not trustworthy.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built in method is definitely more appropriate here

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source,destination,true);
```

However, that is not the heart of the issue. The problem is when each drive is inspected. Specifically, the request for `.VolumeLabel` on the `DirectoryInfo`. You can read some background on the issue at the MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

What it breaks down to is that if a drive is examined, it has to be ready. Sometimes it is not ready and when it is accessed at that point, you get an exception

`IOException - An I/O error occurred (for example, a disk error or a drive was not ready).`

To remedy this, make sure that the drive is ready when accessed with `diagnose.isReady`

```
public static void Save()
{
    string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
    foreach(string drive in drives)
    {
        DriveInfo diagnose = new DriveInfo(drive);
        if(diagnose.IsReady && diagnose.VolumeLabel == @"Backup" && diagnose.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
              ^^Make sure the drive is ready before examining properties
        {
            CopyDirectory(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Source"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Destination"]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend just using the built-in [FileSystem.CopyDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which handles directory copying properly without custom code.

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives the same error, even with that approach.  It almost appears to attempt to read an incorrect drive after it is done.